# How do I vertical aling two text on divs that are side by side?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs side by side displayed with flex to be the same height. I'd like the text inside to be displayed aligned and to stay the same if the parent's div's resizes. I can't figure this one out though. Any Ideas?

To clarify my confusing question, I'd like both text to always display at the same height, so if one grows because text behind is larger, the other one should move to match position.

```css
.row {display: flex;}
.col {flex: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;}
p{margin-top:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>This stay there</h5>
    <p>To be moved</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.<br>This stay there</h5>
    <p>At the same position of this one</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry seems that I dind't explain myself well. I'll try again the first text it's ok where it is I mean the "h5". The one that I want to aling is the "p"

I edited it to clarify. Thanks for all :D

Answer (score 0):

How about using a table-layout to achieve this?

In a table layout, you can use `vertical-align` to have the content display in the middle of their containing cells:

```css
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
p{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    <p>To be moved</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.
    <p>At the same position of this one</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why in the world would you use table when there is flexbox?

Comment: @IanJMiller 1) Because I haven't taken the time to properly learn about flexbox, 2) Because it works well.

Comment: @IanJMiller this is not a table LOL , it is display, and this is suppose to be avalaible in CSS2.1 since 1998 .... where do you mistake HTML and CSS ???, and this will work fine in any browser unless you run an IE7 or lower :)  , But should suggest to use this on the second level, cause text are not side by side anymore in there :)

Comment: @IanJMiller flexbox is one solution, this is another. They're both valid.

Comment: One reason why I avoided using flexbox was lack of support. I suppose at the moment it's pretty solid, but till recently it wasn't so.

Comment: @George the author is already using flexbox so it seems to make more since to just finish going this route than to combine css table with flexbox.

Comment: @IanJMiller I don't disagree with you; I'm saying I'm not the person to tell them how to use flexbox - so I offered an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can imbricate flexbox

**edit**
you can set alignment of content inside a column flexbox via justify-content, since not too clear what you expect, you can test 3 alignements in the snippet below

```css
* body * {
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
h5 {
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
}
p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: lightgray
}
b {
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
}
#spbet:checked ~ .row .col {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#ctr:checked ~ .row .col {
  justify-content: center;
}
#btm:checked ~ .row .col {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#flex1:checked ~ .row .col {
  justify-content: initial;
}
#flex1:checked ~ .row .col h5 {
  flex: 1;
}
aside {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
label {
  border: solid;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: tomato;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="def" name="test">
<input type="radio" id="spbet" name="test">
<input type="radio" id="ctr" name="test">
<input type="radio" id="btm" name="test">
<input type="radio" id="flex1" name="test">
<aside>
  <label for="def"><b>space-around</b>
  </label>
  <label for="spbet"><b>space-between</b>
    <br/>align texts from top to bottom</label>
  <label for="ctr"><b>center
    </b>align at center</label>
  <label for="btm"><b>flex-end
    </b>align at bottom</label>
  <label for="flex1"><b>flex 1
    </b>on h5, no justify-content</label>
</aside>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>This stay there</h5>
    <p>To be moved</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.<br>This stay there</h5>
    <p>At the same position of this one</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The approach with `display:table` to avoid flex could be  :

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.col {
  border: solid;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
p {}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    <p>To be moved</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.
    <p>At the same position of this one</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not work. this leaves the text showing up side by side.

Comment: @IanJMiller side by side ? is it not what you looked for ? okay , i'll edit both snippets (flex and inline-table)

Comment: Your one was the closest one to what i looked for. But the lorem got separeted of the first lorem. I look for both to be aligned. Sorry for the mistakes made u.u.

Comment: @kalolomagno test the snippet about flex and click on the label *align texts from top to bottom*  .. sounds like what you looked for ?

Comment: @kalolomagno i guess after all, CSS won't do it until display grid will be usable :( . You still need at this time javaScript to check and compare heights of element to balance at best the layout. updated first snippet to test 5 configuration on the flexbox to lay h5 and p (a boreder around h2 and a bg for p to see where it stands)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little guide I reference when I forget some things with flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You can use flexbox to acheive what you are trying to do so that the content within the box is always vertically centered.

I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9d831yg8/) and copied the updated css below:

```
.row {display: flex;}
.col {flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;}
 p{margin-top:20px;}
```